# Jetpack compose how to centralize navController and inject it

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, koin, jetpack-compose-navigation

I currently have two `NavGraphs` in my app, one for authentication routes, like login and registration and one for the home routes when logged in.
I currently  need to pass the `navController` as a parameter in every composable when I want to use it. That is definitely not scalable and so I'm wondering if it's possible to make it injectable so that I can just request it through a DI framework like `Koin`. I'm currently using `Koin` in my App so it would be good if I can just use it's dependency injection tools, to inject a `navController` as a `singleton`.

#### Current Navigation setup

I currently create the `navController` inside the `MainActifity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startKoin {
            androidLogger(if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Level.ERROR else Level.NONE)
            androidContext(this@MainActivity)
            modules(listOf(networkModule, viewModelModule, interactorsModule))
        }

        setContent {
            navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()
            SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

I then pass it into the `NavHost` that holds the two `NavGraphs`:

```
fun SetupNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    AnimatedNavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = AUTH_GRAPH_ROUTE,
        route = ROOT_GRAPH_ROUTE
    ) {
        homeNavGraph(navController = navController)
        authNavGraph(navController = navController)
    }
}
```

Below is my `NavGraph` for all authentication routes. I also pass the `NavController` as a parameter so that I can use it inside the screen.

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.authNavGraph(
    navController: NavController
) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = Screen.Login.route,
        route = AUTH_GRAPH_ROUTE
    ) {
        composable(
            Screen.Login.route,
        ) {
            val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = getViewModel()

            LoginScreen(
                navController = navController,
                state = loginViewModel.state.value,
                onTriggerEvent = loginViewModel::onTriggerEvent
            )
        }
        composable(
            Screen.Register.route,
        ) {
            val registerViewModel: RegisterViewModel = getViewModel()
            RegisterScreen(
                navController = navController,
                state = registerViewModel.state.value,
                onTriggerEvent = registerViewModel::onTriggerEvent
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The `NavGraph` for all pages when logged in is similar to my auth one, so not worth showing.

It would be cool if I can just create a `navController` as a `single` through Koin but that is not possible because `rememberNavController` function can only be called inside a Composable.

Is there any solution in solving this problem of passing the `navController` into every nested composable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For easy testing/previewing, it's recommended to pass only handlers instead of the nav controller itself, and do all real navigation inside `SetupNavGraph` when a handler is called. More info can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#testing).

If it doesn't suits you, you can create your own compositional local, like this:

```
val LocalNavController = compositionLocalOf<NavHostController> {
    error("No LocalNavController provided")
}
```

Provide it with `CompositionLocalProvider`:

```
setContent {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalNavController provides rememberAnimatedNavController()) {
        SetupNavGraph()
    }
}
```

And then in any composable inside `CompositionLocalProvider`, you can get your nav controller with `LocalNavController.current`.